# Ruby how to delegate module function of Namespace to Namespace::Base inner class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, ruby-2.3

I was confronted against choosing either #1 :

```
class Abstract
end
class Abstract::Foo < Abstract
end
class Abstract::Bar < Abstract
end
```

versus #2 :

```
module Abstract
  class Base
  end
  class Foo < Base
  end
  class Bar < Base
  end
end
```

I ended up choosing option #2, as my `Abstract` felt more like a namespace, and I could eventually add other things like

```
module Abstract # Instead of class if I had used option #1
  class SomeAbstractService
  end
end
```

However I feel that calling `Abstract::Base.some_class_method` is a bit weird. it possible to add a module function delegation ? For example if my `Base` is an ActiveRecord or Mongoid model (so Foo and Bar are like STI), i'd like to be able to query the collection/table with

`Abstract.where(...)` instead of `Abstract::Base.where(...)`

Is it possible to delegate the module function `.where` to the constant/class `Base` ?

Something like

```
module Abstract
  class Base
  end

  delegate_module_function :where, to: :Base
end
```

Or is there a different/better way to do that ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a standard Ruby library called [Forwardable](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.3.1/libdoc/forwardable/rdoc/SingleForwardable.html).

```
require 'forwardable'

module Abstract
  extend SingleForwardable
  class Base
    def self.where(p)
      "where from base : #{p}"
    end
  end

  delegate :where => Base
end

Abstract.where(id: 3)
# => "where from base : {:id=>3}"
```

For multiple methods, you can write :

```
delegate [:where, :another_method] => Base
```

Comment: This. Modules and classes are objects just like any other object, there is nothing special about them. You would delegate methods between them in exactly the same way you would delegate methods between any other two objects, because they *are* just any other objects.